# insert html after element in an li tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to insert html after the a tag if a li element has children but nothing seems to work. Below is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    $("li ul").hide();
    $("li").each(function() {
        var kids = $(this).children("ul").length;
        if (kids > 0) {
            $('<span class="">SUB</span>').insertAfter(this.closest('a'));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tea</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Green tea</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `jQuery.closest()`  traverses upwards through the parents until the target is found, but in your case an `a` element would be the child of `$(this)`. Perhaps you meant `jQuery.find()`  ?

Comment: Note that in the HTML pane in a Stack Snippet, you only include elements that go in the `body` tag (because when the snippet is run, that's where they'll be put).

Comment: oh... also, `this.closest` is not a function, check your console for errors, you probably meant `$(this).closest()`

Comment: @andrew: It is now, added sometime in the last couple of years, supported on modern browsers: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- Your `$("li").each` will visit **all** `li` elements, not just ones at the top level. Maybe that's a problem, maybe not, but I thought I'd point it out.
- `this` in your `each` callback will be the raw `li` DOM element, but you're then using `this.closest()` (which [exists in modern systems](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest)) to try to find the `a`. But the `a` is a *descendant*, not an ancestor. You wanted `$(this).find()`

Here I've addressed #1 (if it needs addressing) with a more specific selector, and used `$(this).find(...)` for #2:

```js
$(function() {
  $("li ul").hide();
  $("body > ul > li").each(function() {
    var kids = $(this).children("ul").length;
    if (kids > 0) {
      $('<span class="">SUB</span>').insertAfter($(this).find('a').first());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tea</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Green tea</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*(I also removed the elements that shouldn't be in the snippet; see [my comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220326/insert-html-after-element-in-an-li-tag/50220411#comment87457878_50220326) for details.)*

**However**, using jQuery's set-based API, we can make that code simpler:

```js
$(function() {
  $("li ul").hide();
  $("li > a + ul").before(
    '<span class="">SUB</span>'
  );
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tea</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Green tea</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Granted that puts it after the whitespace-only text node between the `a` and the `ul`, whereas your code puts it before that whitespace-only text node. If that's important, we can use `.prev("a").after(...)` instead of `.before(...)`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("li ul").hide();
  $("li > a + ul").prev("a").after(
    '<span class="">SUB</span>'
  );
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tea</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Green tea</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` will look up the tree hierarchy.  You are looping through `li` elements and `a` is a sibling of `ul` not in a parent/child hierarchy.

You could change your selector to:

```
$("<span>SUB</span>").insertAfter($(this).children('a'));
```

See demo

```js
$(function() {
  $("li ul").hide();
  $("li").each(function() {
    var kids = $(this).children("ul").length;
    
    if (kids > 0) {
      $("<span>SUB</span>").insertAfter($(this).children('a'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tea</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Green tea</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```